# Function of an array of values with length dependent on another variable

Tags: functions, list-manipulation

I need to define a function of arbitrarily many variables, whose number is itself a variable of the function.
Schematically it would look as following:

```
Energia[N_, Array[Theta, N/2, 0]_ ] :=  ...
```

In such a case I get the error:

```
Array: Single or list of non-negative machine-sized integers expected at position 2 of Array[Theta,N/2,0].
```

I guess this is due to the fact that N is undefined inside the function argument.
I don't know how to accomodate this need and I have started using Mathematica recently.
Do you have an idea on how to fix this problem?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could put the `Condition` on the *rhs* of the definition, something like `Energia[n_, Array[t,m,0]]:= ... /;m==n/2`.

Comment: Also, `N` is a reserved symbol.  Do not use it as a variable.  By the way, did you use an odd integer for `N`?  If so, the second argument of array indeed would not be an integer.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I corrected the full function definition to: `Energia[\[Tau]_, g_ , NN_, L_, Array[\[Theta], s, 0] ] :=  
 1/\[Pi] Sum[(2 \[Pi])/
      L (-2 Cos[(2 \[Pi])/L m] + \[Tau]) Cos[\[Theta][m]]^2, {m, 0, 
      NN/2 - 1}] - \[Tau] NN/L - 
   g/\[Pi] Sqrt[
     NN/(2 L) - 
      1/(2 \[Pi])
        Sum[(2 \[Pi])/L Cos[\[Theta][m]]^2, {m, 0, N/2 - 1}]] Sum[(
      2 \[Pi])/L (2 \[Pi])/L m Sin[2 \[Theta][m]], {m, 0, NN/2 - 1}] /;
   s == NN/2` but I am still getting that error message. I shared it in case I made a noticeable mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest something like this.  Using a simplified version of the function in the comment:

```
ClearAll@Energia
Energia[τ_, g_, NN_, L_, vars : {__Theta}] /; Length[vars] == NN/2 := 1/π Sum[
   (2 π)/L (-2 Cos[(2 π)/(L m)] + τ) Cos[vars[[m]]]^2,
  {m, 1, NN/2}]
```

Then,

```
Energia[1, 1, 4, 1, Array[Theta, 2, 0]] // Expand
(* -2 Cos[Theta[0]]^2 + 6 Cos[Theta[1]]^2 *)
```

and

```
Energia[1, 1, 4, 1, Array[Theta, 3, 0]] // Expand
(* Energia[1, 1, 4, 1, {Theta[0], Theta[1], Theta[2]}] *)
```

(i.e., it doesn't evaluate).

---

I'd prefer the more general version, where you don't have to specify the variable names:

```
ClearAll@Energia
Energia[τ_, g_, NN_, L_, vars : {__}] /; Length[vars] == NN/2 := 1/π Sum[
   (2 π)/L (-2 Cos[(2 π)/(L m)] + τ) Cos[vars[[m]]]^2,
  {m, 1, NN/2}]
```

Then,

```
Energia[1, 1, 6, 1, {x, y, z}] // Expand
(* -2 Cos[x]^2 + 6 Cos[y]^2 + 4 Cos[z]^2 *)
```

Comment: This strikes me as an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/), though.

Comment: Would you know what the syntax is for the case of two set of variables, i.e., if I need my function to depend on an additional set of variables vars2 with the same length as vars? If I could ask also, would you suggest a good reference to learn Mathematica from the basics, as I feel lost for any such minor modifications? Thanks!